# Dynamically Load p5.js Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, processing, p5.js

I am trying to dynamically load a p5.js script (Processing for the browser), but, no matter what I seem to do, I can't get the script to display its visuals in a webpage. Under normal circumstances, I'd load the p5 script in the index.html, using the standard 
`<script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. When I attempt using a jquery script to dynamically append the script, however, Chrome throws "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience". I've also tried using

```
$('body').load("aSeparateFileWithTheScriptInIt.html", function() {
    console.log("load html was performed");
    $.getScript("sketch.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
      console.log("load sketch was performed");
    });
  });
```

which displays/prints absolutely nothing.

---

Strangely, this code returns that the script ran successfully.

```
$.getScript( "sketch.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

I could use help figuring out how I should properly use jquery to dynamically load the sketch.js file.

Comment: Why do you need to load the script dynamically? And that isn't an error, it's just a warning message. Can you post a [mcve] or link to a jsfiddle we can play with?

Comment: I agree with @KevinWorkman Is there an actual reason you need to dynamically load the script? Can't you just have the script not run until you call a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not exactly what you wanted but i guess reason is the same.
I was load p5js in runtime by adding new script with `async="true"` to the header.

and in my case i didn't see any global functions which supposed to be there with p5.js (in particular `loadImage`, `createCanvas`).

though i was able to see p5 object.

so in my case i had to manually call **`new p5();`** to solve problem.

and that is it, everything is there!

hope it's going to save someone couple hours :)

EDIT 14/05/2019

I end up getting rid of `p5` library completely, and rewriting methods i need by myself.

Mostly because `p5` allows only **one canvas** on the page, and because it is **very slow** comparing to working directly with `canvas` and `canvas context`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to load your sketch asynchronously (to be started long after P5.js has loaded and looked for an existing sketch itself), you will have to add the following lines in order to start the sketch in "global mode"

```
window.setup = setup;
window.draw  = draw;
new p5();
```

`window` is the global variable which P5 fills with all its functions in order to provide the "global mode" environment.

`setup` and `draw` are those user-defined functions, P5 will invoke in order to run your sketch. They must be globally available *before* `new p5()` is run - either because they have been defined as such or because you made them global explicitly (as shown in my example).

The latter allows you to define these two functions in a local environment (e.g. an IIFE) together with any other methods you need (and which you do not want to pollute the global namespace with) and still get rid of the nasty target object prefix (e.g. `p5.xxx`) in front of all P5 methods and properties.

This "solution" is more of a "hack" rather than a real "answer" (as it is undocumented and exploits behavior which might change in the future) but it helped me loading external scripts into an already loaded web page running P5 *without* having to tell those sketches that they will be executed in "local mode" (as a sketch should never need to know the mode it will be run in)