# jQuery getScript() and a div element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, p5.js

I am using jQuery to add a div to a page that I'd want to then use as a location for content produced by another script (in this case ,p5).  It will work fine if I assign include a static div with the id='p5canvas' but when I use jQuery to add dynamic content (see below), nothing happens and I don't understand why.  Can anyone explain what I am getting wrong/what's missing?

main.php

```
<html>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
    <!-- and other stuff-->
    <button class="continueButton" id="btn3" value="blah"> Blah</button>
    <!-- and other stuff-->
</html>
```

jQuery.js

```
$("#btn3").click(function(){
    $("#contentbox3").load("graphic2.html");
    $.getScript("animatebug.js");//a p5 animation
});
```

graphic2.html

```
<div id="p5canvas"></div>
```

animatebug.js

```
function setup(){
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    background(200,100,0);
    img = loadImage("images/bug_small.gif");
    const myCanvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
    myCanvas.parent('p5canvas');
    image(img, 0, 0);
}

function draw(){
    background(200,100,0);
    image(img, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: If that script really only contains two function definitions, then what do you expect to happen? That these functions somehow magically call themselves ...?

Comment: setup() and draw() are boilerplate p5 functions, and render an image because there is a script reference to p5 in the header (which there is).  As I mentioned above, this all works fine when the provide a div id statically.  The issue is when I use jQuery to alter content dynamically it no longer works.  Are you suggesting I need to include a reference to p5 again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938720/dynamically-load-p5-js-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of execution is really important here, and that's where things are going wrong.  The p5 script in your header is looking for a `setup()` function to call at a time when you haven't yet loaded your `<div id="p5canvas"/>` target element or your `animatebug.js` file containing the function.

You need to make sure that both of those two events happen -- html loaded and script loaded -- and then you can execute the script correctly.

You can control when the p5 functions are called by using [p5 instance mode](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html).

```
const animateBug = function(p) {
  let img;

  p.setup = function() {
    const myCanvas = p.createCanvas(400, 400);
    p.background(200, 100, 0);
    img = p.loadImage("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ddffc30b6adba9c402d2f6d8902c47fb?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
    myCanvas.parent('p5canvas');
    p.image(img, 0, 0);
  }

  p.draw = function() {
    p.background(200, 100, 0);
    p.image(img, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

Then you execute this by calling

```
new p5(animateBug);
```

You'll most likely want to call `new p5(animateBug);` in your jQuery so that you can make sure that `load()` and `getScript()` have both finished first.  But I'm not a jQuery pro so I can't help you with that part.